On strong convexity of the squared norm of an affine function.
Let $V,W$ be Hilbert spaces. Let $f:V \to W$ be a bounded affine function. That is, $f(x)=A(x)+b$ for some bounded linear function $A:V \to W$ and fixed $b \in W$. Since $V$ is a Hilbert space, the induced squared norm $\|.\|^2$ is strongly convex. Take the function $g(x):=\|f(x)\|^2$. Suppose I know that $g$ is strictly convex. Does this imply that it is strongly convex?
In the finite dimensional case, I believe the answer is yes. Here is my attempt at a proof: We know $\|x\|^2 = x^TQx$ for some $Q>0$ since the norm is induced from an inner product. So, $g(x) = (Ax+b)^TQ(Ax+b) = x^TA^TQAx + 2x^TA^TQb + b^TQb$. A strictly convex quadratic function must be strongly convex.
Is this true for arbitrary Hilbert spaces?

A must be full column rank

@goldboy I'm dealing with an infinite dimensional case though.

You should be able to answer this question based on the answer to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957748/for-quadratic-functions-on-arbitrary-hilbert-spaces-does-strict-convexity-still/4958175#4958175
