For quadratic functions on arbitrary Hilbert spaces, does strict convexity still imply strongly convexity?
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable real Hilbert space. Let $q:\mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded quadratic function. By this, I mean $q(x)=(Qx,x)+(b,x)+c$ for some self-adjoint bounded linear operator $Q$, $b \in \mathcal{H}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose we know that $q$ is strictly convex. Does this imply that $q$ is strongly convex? In finite dimensions, the answer is yes as this would imply $Q$ must be positive-definite. I was curious if this holds for arbitrary separable Hilbert spaces as well.

No. Take $H=l^2$ and
$$
q(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k x_k^2.
$$
